# correct way to append data into UITableView, swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to add new data to a UITableView using two ways

1. **The First way**

   ```
   func insertData(appendMessages:[Message]) {
       var currentCount = self.messeges.count;
       var indxesPath:[NSIndexPath] = [NSIndexPath]()
       for msg in appendMessages {
           indxesPath.append(NSIndexPath(forRow:currentCount,inSection:0));

           self.messeges.append(msg)
           currentCount++
       }

       self.tableView.beginUpdates()
       self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indxesPath, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
       self.tableView.endUpdates()
   }
   ```
2. **The Second way**

   ```
   func insertData(appendMessages:[Message]) {
       for msg in appendMessages {
           self.messeges.append(msg)
       }
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
   ```

You see I have separated results.

When using "reloadData" all is working fine, but I guess this is not good cause I am updating all and not new content?

When using "insertRowsAtIndexPaths" I have duplicated separator and the row is painted only when I am clicking on it

This is weird, what I am doing wrong...

Thank you

Shay

[image: image where using reloadData]
[image: image when using insertRowsAtIndexPaths]

Comment: I don't know anything about Swift, but the traditional Objective-C API basically prohibits directly editing the list. The correct method is to add new elements to the table view's data source (delegate).

Comment: jsumners, it doesn’t look like that’s the problem here—if `self.messeges` is the model object being used by the data source, calling `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` should be fine. Problems with that usually arise when the insertions are inconsistent with the final state of the data source, and those usually cause a crash.

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon thanks, yes `self.messeges` is the model being used. what to you mean by "insertions are inconsistent with the final state of the data source", how can i fix that ?

Answer (score -1):

Error is that you should initialise the counter at 0 then increase it:

```
func insertData(appendMessages:[Message]) {
    var currentCount = 0
    var indexesPath = [NSIndexPath]()
    for _ in appendMessages {
        let index = let index = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)            
        indexesPath.append(index)
        currentCount++
    }

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexesPath, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```