# TableView Load More is fetching non-stop

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I setup a TableView and fetching paginated data. For page 1, as it's hitting route without any parameter (e.g `/?page=2`). Now I am trying to implement infinite scroll kind load more. I am trying to make a call everytime it hits the 5th row from bottom.

What this code does is fetches non-stop as soon as I hit the 5th cell from bottom. I think it's because the table stays on the 5th cell from bottom and keep adding cells from bottom toward up (but it may be just visual illusion)

```
class TableView1: UITableViewController {

  var currentPage: Int = 1
  var results: [JSON]? = []
  var urlEndpoint: String?
  var isLoading = false

  override func viewDidLoad() {
       loadItems()
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // connections to cell..

    let rowsToLoadFromBottom = 5;
    let rowsLoaded = self.results?.count   // count of fetched items

    if (!isLoading && (indexPath.row >= (rowsLoaded! - rowsToLoadFromBottom))) {
            self.loadItems()
    }

    return cell
   }
```

And `loadItems()` function:

```
   func loadItems() {
      isLoading = true
      urlEndpoint = "http://appurl.app/feed"

   if currentPage != 1 {
        currentPage = currentPage! + 1
        urlEndpoint = "http://appurl.app/feed?page=\(currentPage)"
        // print(urlEndpoint)
    }

   // Alamofire call.. {
       // Error handling

      // Got results {
             self.currentPage = json["current_page"].integer
             self.currentPage = self.currentPage + 1

             self.results = data
             self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
          self.isLoading = false
      }
   }
```

**Update**: I made it fetch properly. Now, I am seeing the links with `page` parameters on console. However, now it's loading all pages in a sudden (I have 6 pages, so 6 of them) so it doesn't really stop appending and I can actually see like a loop.

**Update 2:**

```
self.currentPage = json["current_page"].int!

if self.currentPage == 1 {
   self.results = data // data is json data fetched
   self.tableView.reloadData()
} else {
   var currentCount = self.results!.count;
   let indxesPath : [NSIndexPath] = [NSIndexPath]()

   for result in data {
      self.results?.append(result)
      currentCount++
   }

   self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indxesPath, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
   }                     
  self.currentPage = self.currentPage + 1
  }
  self.isLoading = false
```

But it's crashing on line `self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indxesPath, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)`

> The error: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (40) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (20), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Comment: Any difference if you set self.loading = false BEFORE reloading the tableView?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It doesn't. It feels like it's falling in a loop when i hit to bottom and don't pull it up. Update: I changed of currentPage from the String? to Int? I updated the OP

Comment: Rather than calling reloadData when you lose the new data (which will reload the whole table and can be visually jarring) you should call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` in a loop with the new data (probably inbetween calls to begin/end updates) do you can control the scrolling and avoid the continuous load

Comment: @Paulw11 Please check the update I added to the question. What should I do in the else part? I receive data as json and in true statement, I pass it to results and reloadData. But how should I use it in the else? I understand I should add a for loop to append each object to each cell by using insertRowsAtIndexPaths, however I got confused how I should apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513667/correct-way-to-append-data-into-uitableview-swift). Here it is applied to my scenario

```
if self.currentPage == 1 {
    self.results = data
    self.tableView.reloadData()
} else {
    var currentCount = self.results!.count;
    var indxesPath : [NSIndexPath] = [NSIndexPath]()

    for result in data {
       indxesPath.append(NSIndexPath(forRow:currentCount,inSection:0));
       self.results?.append(result)
       currentCount++
    }

    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indxesPath, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
}
```